# Python psycog2 | Use a tuple or array in where clause

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, tuples, psycopg2

I have a tuple like as shown below

```py
vilist = (1,2,3,4)
```

I am trying to use them in Psycopg2 query like as shown below

```py
sql = "select * from temp.table1 where ids in {}"
cur.execute(sql,vilist)
```

Which should parse a SQL string like

```sql
SELECT * FROM temp.table1 WHERE ids IDS (1,2,3,4);
```

However, I get an error like as shown below

```py
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-64f840fa2abe> in <module>
      1 sql = "select * from temp.table1 where ids in {}"
----> 2 cur.execute(sql,vilist)

SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...rom temp.table1 where ids in {}
```

Can help me resolve this error please.

Comment: klin - the example shows for single value but I wnt to pass a tuple containing multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SQL string composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) to pass identifiers or literals to a query text.

```py
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.sql as sql
# ...

vilist = (1,2,3,4)
query = sql.SQL("select * from temp.table1 where ids in {}").format(sql.Literal(vilist))
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: It results in error like `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'SQL'` which am trying to find online as t what is causing this error

Comment: I tried both `sql.sql` and `sql.SQL` but it doesn't work..

Comment: You have a string variable `sql` - note, that I have changed it to `query`. Delete `sql` variable from the script.